# Dissimilarity function for Text Mining in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am using the TM package in R to perform Clustering on Text Documents. While running the dissimilarity function on a TDM I am facing the following Error

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dissimilarity’ for signature ‘"TermDocumentMatrix"’
```

Code Snippet

```
docsTDM <- tm_map(docs8,PlainTextDocument)
docsTDM1 <- TermDocumentMatrix(docsTDM)
docsdissim <- dissimilarity(docsTDM1, method = "cosine")
```

I am referencing the following link to reach to the docs8 step

http://www.r-bloggers.com/text-mining-in-r-automatic-categorization-of-wikipedia-articles/

Comment: Try lsf.str("package:tm") and you will see the tm package has no such function.  Here is a SO question that might guide you.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31565/is-there-an-r-function-that-will-compute-the-cosine-dissimilarity-matrix

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the function `dissimilarity()` is no longer supported in the `tm` package, so the code you're looking at won't work.

See the 'Deprecated and Defunct' section in the recent [package updates](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/news.html) for `tm`.

The authors suggest using `proxy::dist()` instead.